SupersetError(message='Errno 111 Connection refused')
I have setup Apache Superset-3.0.4 through docker. Now, I am trying to setup alerts and reports email, but I am getting
superset_worker         | A downstream exception occurred while generating a report: d71d4983-558a-4aad-bec4-1ff2e4ef604d. [SupersetError(message='[Errno 111] Connection refused', error_type=<SupersetErrorType.REPORT_NOTIFICATION_ERROR: 'REPORT_NOTIFICATION_ERROR'>, level=<ErrorLevel.ERROR: 'error'>, extra=None)]
superset_worker         | Traceback (most recent call last):
superset_worker         |   File "/app/superset/tasks/scheduler.py", line 98, in execute
superset_worker         |     ).run()
superset_worker         |   File "/app/superset/commands/report/execute.py", line 729, in run
superset_worker         |     raise ex
superset_worker         |   File "/app/superset/commands/report/execute.py", line 727, in run
superset_worker         |     ).run()
superset_worker         |   File "/app/superset/commands/report/execute.py", line 689, in run
superset_worker         |     ).next()
superset_worker         |   File "/app/superset/commands/report/execute.py", line 586, in next
superset_worker         |     raise first_ex
superset_worker         |   File "/app/superset/commands/report/execute.py", line 555, in next
superset_worker         |     self.send()
superset_worker         |   File "/app/superset/commands/report/execute.py", line 453, in send
superset_worker         |     self._send(notification_content, self._report_schedule.recipients)
superset_worker         |   File "/app/superset/commands/report/execute.py", line 442, in _send
superset_worker         |     raise ReportScheduleSystemErrorsException(errors=notification_errors)
superset_worker         | superset.commands.report.exceptions.ReportScheduleSystemErrorsException: [SupersetError(message='[Errno 111] Connection refused', error_type=<SupersetErrorType.REPORT_NOTIFICATION_ERROR: 'REPORT_NOTIFICATION_ERROR'>, level=<ErrorLevel.ERROR: 'error'>, extra=None)]
superset_worker         | [2024-04-24 09:15:14,311: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-15] A downstream exception occurred while generating a report: d71d4983-558a-4aad-bec4-1ff2e4ef604d. [SupersetError(message='[Errno 111] Connection refused', error_type=<SupersetErrorType.REPORT_NOTIFICATION_ERROR: 'REPORT_NOTIFICATION_ERROR'>, level=<ErrorLevel.ERROR: 'error'>, extra=None)]
superset_worker         | Traceback (most recent call last):
superset_worker         |   File "/app/superset/tasks/scheduler.py", line 98, in execute
superset_worker         |     ).run()
superset_worker         |   File "/app/superset/commands/report/execute.py", line 729, in run
superset_worker         |     raise ex
superset_worker         |   File "/app/superset/commands/report/execute.py", line 727, in run
superset_worker         |     ).run()
superset_worker         |   File "/app/superset/commands/report/execute.py", line 689, in run
superset_worker         |     ).next()
superset_worker         |   File "/app/superset/commands/report/execute.py", line 586, in next
superset_worker         |     raise first_ex
superset_worker         |   File "/app/superset/commands/report/execute.py", line 555, in next
superset_worker         |     self.send()
superset_worker         |   File "/app/superset/commands/report/execute.py", line 453, in send
superset_worker         |     self._send(notification_content, self._report_schedule.recipients)
superset_worker         |   File "/app/superset/commands/report/execute.py", line 442, in _send
superset_worker         |     raise ReportScheduleSystemErrorsException(errors=notification_errors)
superset_worker         | superset.commands.report.exceptions.ReportScheduleSystemErrorsException: [SupersetError(message='[Errno 111] Connection refused', error_type=<SupersetErrorType.REPORT_NOTIFICATION_ERROR: 'REPORT_NOTIFICATION_ERROR'>, level=<ErrorLevel.ERROR: 'error'>, extra=None)]

rest of functionality is working fine, able create dashboards and all. Also it is able to connect to postgres db which i am using to create charts and dashboards.
This is superset_config.py
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#
# This file is included in the final Docker image and SHOULD be overridden when
# deploying the image to prod. Settings configured here are intended for use in local
# development environments. Also note that superset_config_docker.py is imported
# as a final step as a means to override "defaults" configured here
#
import logging
import os

from celery.schedules import crontab
from flask_caching.backends.filesystemcache import FileSystemCache

logger = logging.getLogger()

DATABASE_DIALECT = os.getenv("DATABASE_DIALECT")
DATABASE_USER = os.getenv("DATABASE_USER")
DATABASE_PASSWORD = os.getenv("DATABASE_PASSWORD")
DATABASE_HOST = os.getenv("DATABASE_HOST")
DATABASE_PORT = os.getenv("DATABASE_PORT")
DATABASE_DB = os.getenv("DATABASE_DB")

EXAMPLES_USER = os.getenv("EXAMPLES_USER")
EXAMPLES_PASSWORD = os.getenv("EXAMPLES_PASSWORD")
EXAMPLES_HOST = os.getenv("EXAMPLES_HOST")
EXAMPLES_PORT = os.getenv("EXAMPLES_PORT")
EXAMPLES_DB = os.getenv("EXAMPLES_DB")

# The SQLAlchemy connection string.
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = (
    f"{DATABASE_DIALECT}://"
    f"{DATABASE_USER}:{DATABASE_PASSWORD}@"
    f"{DATABASE_HOST}:{DATABASE_PORT}/{DATABASE_DB}"
)

SQLALCHEMY_EXAMPLES_URI = (
    f"{DATABASE_DIALECT}://"
    f"{EXAMPLES_USER}:{EXAMPLES_PASSWORD}@"
    f"{EXAMPLES_HOST}:{EXAMPLES_PORT}/{EXAMPLES_DB}"
)

REDIS_HOST = os.getenv("REDIS_HOST", "redis")
REDIS_PORT = os.getenv("REDIS_PORT", "6379")
REDIS_CELERY_DB = os.getenv("REDIS_CELERY_DB", "0")
REDIS_RESULTS_DB = os.getenv("REDIS_RESULTS_DB", "1")

RESULTS_BACKEND = FileSystemCache("/app/superset_home/sqllab")

CACHE_CONFIG = {
    "CACHE_TYPE": "RedisCache",
    "CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT": 300,
    "CACHE_KEY_PREFIX": "superset_",
    "CACHE_REDIS_HOST": REDIS_HOST,
    "CACHE_REDIS_PORT": REDIS_PORT,
    "CACHE_REDIS_DB": REDIS_RESULTS_DB,
}
DATA_CACHE_CONFIG = CACHE_CONFIG


class CeleryConfig:
    broker_url = f"redis://{REDIS_HOST}:{REDIS_PORT}/{REDIS_CELERY_DB}"
    imports = ("superset.sql_lab",)
    result_backend = f"redis://{REDIS_HOST}:{REDIS_PORT}/{REDIS_RESULTS_DB}"
    worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1
    task_acks_late = False
    beat_schedule = {
        "reports.scheduler": {
            "task": "reports.scheduler",
            "schedule": crontab(minute="*", hour="*"),
        },
        "reports.prune_log": {
            "task": "reports.prune_log",
            "schedule": crontab(minute=10, hour=0),
        },
    }


CELERY_CONFIG = CeleryConfig

FEATURE_FLAGS = {"ALERT_REPORTS": True}
ALERT_REPORTS_NOTIFICATION_DRY_RUN = False
WEBDRIVER_BASEURL = "http://superset:8088/"
# The base URL for the email report hyperlinks.
WEBDRIVER_BASEURL_USER_FRIENDLY = WEBDRIVER_BASEURL

SQLLAB_CTAS_NO_LIMIT = True

# Email configuration
SMTP_HOST = "127.0.0.1" 
SMTP_STARTTLS = False
SMTP_SSL_SERVER_AUTH = True
SMTP_SSL = True
SMTP_USER = "xxx"
SMTP_PORT = 25 # your port eg. 587
SMTP_PASSWORD = "xxxx"
SMTP_MAIL_FROM = "example@example.com"


#
# Optionally import superset_config_docker.py (which will have been included on
# the PYTHONPATH) in order to allow for local settings to be overridden
#
try:
    import superset_config_docker
    from superset_config_docker import *  # noqa

    logger.info(
        f"Loaded your Docker configuration at " f"[{superset_config_docker.__file__}]"
    )
except ImportError:
    logger.info("Using default Docker config...")

created fresh SMTP(postfix) user and using that in SMTP configuration.
My goal is to send email for Alerting and Reporting. And iam using superset3.0.4. Please help me on this.
Note: I have hosted the superset on GCP VM, due organisation norms it is not connected with internet also.
